# Java serialization to XML

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb, duplicates

I am currently serializing my Java instances using the default Java serialization mechanism. I would like to switch to another format that is independent of the Java version. I considered using JAXB, but I think I encounter problems with duplicates. In particular, consider the following:

```
A a = new A();
B b = new B();
C c = new C();
a.c = c;
b.c = c;
```

If I were to serialize a and b using the default Java serialization mechanism, I would only end up with one instance of c. JAXB would serialize this twice (unless I am mistaken, please correct me).

What's the best option for me here? Is there a way I can turn my already-serialized instances into XML some other way?

Comment: you are correct, you will get multiple instances.  however, with the exception of a few bugs here and there, java serialization _is_ independent of the java version, so it's not clear to me why you want to switch.

Comment: As @jthalborn wrote, java serialization is pretty stable over java versions. Most issues arise if your objects change and you did not set a serialization id to control compatibility. Also, of course, it is not portable in any way.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own serializer/deserializer. But to reach what you want, you would have to keep the state of every `c` as XML in `c`.

You could implement a `getXml()` method in your objects somehow like this

```
Node getXml() {
    if( this.nodeCache == null ) 
        ... create nodeCache node from c ...

    return this.nodeCache;
}
```

To build your XML, you request each child object as a node and link it into your final DOM tree. Then you write the DOM to disk.

The complexity here is to find the right places in your application when your node cache is dirty. I don't know if any automatic serializer is around that supports you with this.

Answer (score -1):

## "Simple XML Serialization" project

Check out the [Simple XML Serialization](http://simple.sourceforge.net/) project. It is indeed very simple way to write out an object’s data to storage, and if need be, later re-hydrate that data into an object again.

Much simpler than JAXB. You can get started in minutes by looking at the examples in the docs. "Simple" is good for when you have simple situations that do not call for all of JAXB’s features and flexibility.

My only frustration in using this solid library is the difficulty in googling brought by its particular name.

Comment: Dear Down-Voter, please leave a critique along with your vote.